# Facebook - How can I distinguish page admin roles in my tab application?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

1. Iv'e created a Facebook application, and installed it in my page.
2. Using the signed_request I can see if a specific user is a page admin.

Q:How can I get the admin user role?

```
Manager
Content Creator
Moderator
Advertiser
Insights Analyst
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, just that they have one - if you need to know the specific role you need them to Authorise your app with the `manage_pages` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) and then you can check via the Pages API